# Does Autodesk Forge errors always contain the same JSON format?

Tags: error-handling, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I've created an app in the Design Automation API, and I'm trying to handle any possible errors. does every error response from Forge have the same error object format?

**If so, what is the format?**

Comment: The errors you meet may be of two kinds, ones coming from Forge Design Automation rest API - Refer https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/troubleshooting/
There can be errors coming from your app bundle, for example for AutoCAD https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/autocad-design-automation-error-codes

Comment: Your answer is referring to the http status codes, not the JSON format of the errors. For example, sometimes an error response will have a "developerMessage" key. What is the main key in Autodesk's error JSON object that I can be looking for?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I will get back to you.